# Autosave and Custom Fields in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, autosave

I was having the problem with WordPress autosave not sending custom field data, and found this entry on SO:

[Wordpress add_meta_box() weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539951/wordpress-add-meta-box-weirdness)

The approved answer works, but is it not just preventing any autosave from happening by returning early? Isn't the same as disabling autosave completely? If so, wouldn't it be better to do so in the proper way instead of letting it try to autosave just to prevent it?

The only exception I could see is if one checked for a post-type before checking for autosave so that you only disabled autosave for certain post types.

I'm going to be disabling autosave completely, but was wondering what you guys thought.

EDIT: I'm not having problems with the autosave anymore. This question is to discuss the merits of the solutions that I mentioned above.

Additionally, I can't see how this would be a feature of WordPress, and would assume that autosave should be changed to include all post data. No?

Comment: why is this question closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the linked answer does not disable autosave, it only stops a custom save function executing when autosaving. This is necessary because the Wordpress autosave system does not support post meta data (custom fields), either in the Javascript which collates the post data or in the PHP which creates and restores revisions.

Comment: I know it doesn't disable autosave explicitly, but isn't that what it's doing in effect? Isn't the code attaching an extra function to the save event that basically says if it's an autosave, don't do anything?

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you're saying... the autosave continues, but doesn't include the empty custom slots that would have happened. So autosave works, but only autosaves the title/editor/etc. default fields?

Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following for Custom Fields I've created and it's worked fine.

```
<?php
// Save Fields
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
 if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return $post_id;
 global $post;
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_featuring", $_POST["event_featuring"]);
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_time", $_POST["event_time"]);
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", $_POST["event_date"]);
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_end_date", $_POST["event_end_date"]);
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_location", $_POST["event_location"]);
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "bhs_event", $_POST["bhs_event"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I know it works fine, but my question is more about if it really is a good solution or if it can be fixed earlier up the chain of events. More general question about the merits of the solution.

Comment: My bad.  I'm really not sure.  I just recently created meta_boxes so I was quick to paste my working code.  I should have read into your question more.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the solution posted here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-information-disappearing worked for me and I think is much more elegant.